# If the divergence of an isotropic vector field (in 3d Euclidean space) is a constant, what is it's dependence on the co-ordinates?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, vector-fields, turbulence

Basically the title. In symbols, I have
\begin{equation}
   \nabla \cdot F = - 4 \varepsilon \ ,
\end{equation}
where $\varepsilon$ is a constant, and there is isotropy. My guess was $F$ can depend only on the radial co-ordinate, hence it becomes
\begin{equation}
 \frac{1}{r^2} \partial_r (r^2 F_r) + \frac{1}{r \sin \theta} \partial_\theta ( F_\theta \sin \theta ) + \frac{1}{r^2 \sin^2 \theta}  \partial_\phi F_\phi= - 4 \varepsilon \ ,
\end{equation}
where all three $(F_r,F_\theta,F_\phi)$ depend only on $r$. Hence,
\begin{align}
 \frac{1}{r^2} \partial_r (r^2F_r) + \frac{ F_\theta \cot \theta}{r } = - 4 \varepsilon \ \\
\implies \frac{1}{r F_\theta} \partial_r (r^2F_r) + \cot \theta = - 4 \frac{\varepsilon r}{F_\theta} \ .
\end{align}
This is in a separable form as the first term in rhs and the lhs both depend only on $r$, hence it must be that $F_\theta = 0$. (Side question - Could this have been anticipated?)

So we are faced with,
\begin{equation}
 \frac{1}{r^2} \partial_r (r^2F_r) = - 4 \varepsilon \ ,
\end{equation}
whose solution is
\begin{equation}
 F_r = - \frac{4}{3} \varepsilon r \ .
\end{equation}
The answer has $4/5$ instead of $4/3$ in front of $\varepsilon r$.

On Boundary Condition: Actually I don't know the precise boundary condition. So I should say find *a* solution to the PDE. But $F$ is a correlation function for some random field, and we are interested in leading order behavior for small $r$. We know by dimensional analysis that it could only be $F \propto \varepsilon r $, so adding homogeneous stuff to it like $\nabla \times A$ or a solution to Laplace's equation is not allowed. I guess it is only an asymptotic boundary condition then $F \sim r$ for $r \to 0$.

Further context: The author [of this arxiv article](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0007106) has a slick way of deriving Kolmogorov's 4/5 law, without the full machinery of Karmann-Howarth. He considers the incompressible Navier-Stokes equation with white noise forcing, and proceeds to derive a relation between 2-point noise correlation and 3-point velocity correlation, which is equation (11). As I had not seen equation (14) of the article before (it seems reasonable, I guess I could just read more on it), I am attempting to go from equation (13) to equation (15) on my own.

Comment: Note that you wrote $u$ instead of $F$ twice. Also yes, when $F$ is assumed to be independent of $\theta$ and $\phi$, those partial derivatives $F_\theta$ and $F_\phi$ vanish.

Comment: Thanks. I was using u when I started writing and unsure whether to link the article, then recalled that it uses u for something else and switched to F. Regarding the second, that was used in going from equation (2) to (3) here, where I dropped $\partial_\phi F_\phi$, but $F_\theta$ just comes out of $\partial_\theta$.

Comment: You do not specify boundary conditions for your differential equation. Without it, there is no unique solution. If you have one solution $F_0$ and you add the gradient of any scalar field $\Phi$ to it (i.e. $F_1 = F_0 + \nabla \Phi$), which satisfies the Laplace equation $\Delta \Phi = 0$, you get another solution.

Comment: @ oliver  Yeah forgot about that. Will edit.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the differential equation is concerned, my solution is correct. However I had misinterpreted the meaning of $F = F_r \; e_r$; here it is the correlation of longitudinal velocity fluctuations to the total velocity fluctuation squared i.e $\langle \Delta_{\parallel} v \; | \Delta v |^2 \rangle$. The Kolomogorov's 4/5 law is a statement regarding the third moment of (only) longitudinal fluctuations  i.e $\langle | \Delta_{ \parallel} v |^3 \rangle$. If we subtract off the transverse components i.e use
$$\langle \Delta_{\parallel} v \; | \Delta v |^2 \rangle = \langle | \Delta_{ \parallel} v |^3 \rangle +  \langle   \Delta_{\parallel} v \; | \Delta_{\perp} v |^2 \rangle \ ,$$
whose second term needs to be evaluated separately using a similar differential equation, then we get the required
$$\langle | \Delta_{\parallel} v |^3 \rangle = -\frac{4}{5} \varepsilon r \ .$$